# Send email from docker container using host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sendmail

I'm running multiple containers on a CentOS server. The containers have an application running which requires sending notification emails to users. The host server has the capability to send emails however when trying sendmail using the containers I get the following error:

`Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]`

I need to achieve this without using host networking on the containers.

I've tried enabling the sendmail daemon to listen to docker0 on port 2525 by editing the sendmail.cf file to have the following line:

```
O DaemonPortOptions=Port=2525,Addr=172.17.0.1, Name=MTADocker
```

Appreciate any tip you can provide, been trying this for a while without any success.

Comment: is mapping the port allowed?

Comment: @aran it states that the port is already in use, both port 2525 and 25 are currently used by sendmail

Comment: I also did the following just now to check and it seems to have changed the error I receive on the container.

On the host server I changed sendmail.cf as follows:

#O DaemonPortOptions=Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA
O DaemonPortOptions=Port=smtp, Name=MTA

Now I receive the following error within the container:

domain.com: Name server timeout
email@domain.com... Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery
email@domain.com... queued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by port forwarding docker container port 25 to docker host.